# Is there a way to restart audio without restarting a Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

Sometimes, when I start my machine, the volume control is set to 100, but it plays relatively quiet. I can fix it by rebooting my machine. Is there a way to restart audio devices, without rebooting the computer?

Comment: have you tried to go into the device manager, find audio file, click right mouse button on it and choose disable. After that once again and choose enable. Hope it works ;)

Comment: Nice idea, device manager lists two "High Definition Audio Device"s under "Sound, video and game controllers". I am able to disable one of them but when I try to disable the second I get a prompt asking to reboot my machine.

Comment: Try updating your audio drivers too.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I also had to stop AudioEndpointBuilder and restart it

```
net stop audiosrv
net stop AudioEndpointBuilder
net start audiosrv
net start AudioEndpointBuilder
```

If you look at Windows' [Task Manager's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) "services" tab, that might help you identify what services you have tied to audio.

Comment: On my system, `net start audiosrv` also started `AudioEndpointBuilder` so no need for the final line.

Comment: This doesn't work for my case using Windows 7 32-bit on a HP Mini netbook. Sleeping and waking the computer usually fixes it but in some situations (such as partially buffered YouTube videos) this can have other annoying side effects besides fixing the sound.

Comment: Similar to @xylar comment: **Windows Audio** service is dependent on **Windows Audio Endpoint Builder**.  Typically when you want to manually start/stop services that involve dependencies they should be nested in the form: `stop A`, `stop B`, `start B`, `start A`, where `A` depends on `B`.  Another option is to use `services.msc` and Restart the lowest level service, which in this case is `Windows Audio Endpoint Builder`.  That automatically executes all the above in proper order.

Comment: can we use use wildecard???

Comment: SO glad I decided to Google this! -- put the above in a batch script, and BAM, my audio is working again! -- No more need to restart every time my audio craps out on me. -- Freaking awesome. :D

Comment: I also had to restart `CTAudSvcService` (Creative Audio Service)

Comment: Not for Windows 10 :(

Comment: In Windows 10 it may help if you start cmd in Administrator mode.

Comment: This solution worked for me in Windows 8. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

Open up a command prompt as administrator and run:

```
net stop audiosrv
net start audiosrv
```

This restarts the Windows service responsible for handling audio.

Comment: Thanks god, stupid drivers crashing audio jack on log out.

Comment: Not for Windows 10 :(

Answer (score 12):

For Windows 7, I used this and hope it will work for all Windows flavors:

1. Right click on *My Computer*
2. Chose *Manage*
3. Select *Device Manager* in the left panel
4. Expand *Sound, video and game controllers*
5. Find your audio driver and right click on it.
6. Chose *Disable*
7. Right click on the audio driver again
8. Chose *Enable*

It should start working now.

Comment: Not for Windows 10 :(

Comment: Not for Windows 7 either, at least not if you care about the "without restarting" part of the question.

Comment: @kokbira You can access it using Windows Settings -> Hardware

Comment: This worked on Windows 10. I clicked on `View` menu / `View Devices by Connection` and then disabled/reenabled the root item `Intel...Audio Controller` instead of the child `Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)`. **BOOM** I got windows audio working again without restart.

Answer (score 1):

Check your device manager and go to audio in and outputs. Now check the box show hidden devices (in view) and delete all the devices other than the ones that you have when you didn't show the hidden devices. Reboot.

There must have been some leftover drivers that interfered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, it helped me too. Something stuck in my sound card buffer and kept looping.
I was not able to disable my card in Device Manager, (it wanted to restart Windows 7).
But stopping the service helped, (though only that did not solve my problem alone).

So this is what I did:

```
net stop audiosrv
net stop AudioEndpointBuilder
```

Then I was bale to disable the audio device in Device Manager.
Then I re-enabled it, and

```
net start audiosrv
```

This reset my card and solved my issue.

Comment: Not for Windows 10 :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem is intensely annoying. I have found a solution that works for me. It isn't permanent as you have to do it each time the speakers stop, but it is better than restarting all the time.

Go to Device Manager
Right click on Sound video and game controllers
and click "scan for hardware changes"

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for a way to restart my Creative X-Fi Titanium driver w/out restarting.  Sometimes when I change the Mode, I'll get a buzz out of the right channel that may force me to restart Win7 several times to get rid of.

This fix didn't work for me but as I was unable to Disable the X-Fi in the Device Mgr., which stated it would require a restart when I tried.  I'd tried to kill all related software, but maybe there was something I missed, being the massive driver that it is.